# Ensure blocking of database rows during the Entity Framework request

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have created service which communicates with my database. `GetAvailableUserId` service's method cannot be run simultaneously, because I don't want to return same user's id for two different calls. So far I have managed this:

```
public class UserService : IUserService
{
    public int GetAvailableUserId()
    {
        using (var context = new UsersEntities())
        {
            using (var transaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
            {
                var availableUser = context.User
                    .Where(x => x.Available)
                    .FirstOrDefault();

                if (availableUser == null)
                {
                    throw new Exception("No available users.");
                }

                availableUser.Available = false;
                context.SaveChanges();
                transaction.Commit();

                return availableUser.Id;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I wanted to test if service will work as intended, so I created simple console application to simulate synchronous requests:

```
Parallel.For(1, 100, (i, state) => {
    var service = new UserServiceReference.UserServiceClient();
    var id = service.GetAvailableUserId();
});
```

Unfortunately, It failed that simple test. I can see, that it returned same id for different `for` iterations.

Whats wrong there?

Comment: Hi did you give the db concurrency example I showed a try against your test?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you wan to lock method from other threads. If yesm then use `lock`:

```
static object lockObject = new object();

public class UserService : IUserService
{
    public int GetAvailableUserId()
    {
         lock(lockObject )
         {
              // your code is omitted for the brevity
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative method to achieve this is to catch DbUpdateConcurrencyException to check whether values in the row have changed since retrieving when you try to save.

So if e.g. the same record is retrieved twice. The first one to have the Available value updated in the database will cause the other one to thow concurrency exception when it tries to save because the value has changed since it was retrieved.

[Microsoft - handling Concurrency Conflicts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/concurrency).

Add ConcurrencyCheck attribute above the Available property in your entity.

```
  [ConcurrencyCheck]
    public bool Available{ get; set; }
```

Then:

```
 public int GetAvailableUserId()
    {
        using (var context = new UsersEntities())
        {
          try
            {
                var availableUser = context.User
                    .Where(x => x.Available)
                    .FirstOrDefault();

                if (availableUser == null)
                {
                    throw new Exception("No available users.");
                }

                availableUser.Available = false;
                context.SaveChanges();

                return availableUser.Id;
             }
             catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
             {
                //If same row was already retrieved and updated to false, do not save, instead call the method again to get the next true row. 
                return GetAvailableUserId();
             }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to spend some time and delve into the intricadies of SQL Server and EntityFramework.

Basically:

- You need a database connection that handles repeatable results (which is a database connection string setting).
- You need to wrap the interactions in EntityFramework within one transaction so that multiple instances do not possibly return the same result in the query and then make problems in the save.